# How good is Cassette at performance during multiple client requests?

Tags: asp.net, iis, caching, cassette

We are considering using Cassette in our asp.net web application which might be accessed by hundreds of users at the same time. Cassette works through HTTP handler which handles requests starting like this:

```
'_cassette\assets\*'
```

I notice that no bundle is created on a hard drive; it looks like resources are compiled and zipped at run-time in memory and returned back to the user.

Does it mean that Cassette relies on proxy or IIS cache, and not on a browser cache to handle all subsequent requests from other users to the same bundle? Does `Cache-Control: public` added to every bundle response means the bundle for the URL will *always* be cached by IIS/proxy and the web application will not do a double job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassette caches generated bundles in Isolated Storage on the server disk. 
(but only in Release mode)